# PIC18 Assembly Handling 16 bits

Tags: pic

I've got a colour sensor that is semi-functional at the moment. I am fairly new to Assembly, PIC especially, and I am confused as to how to handle a "high" and "low" address for a number. Let me explain.

When I read from my colour sensor, I have to read from a high and low address. This much is not a problem, rather my issue is processing this number after I read it. The tutorial that I followed does something like this:

```
colour1 = (addrH << 8) | addrL ...
```

Which makes sense: we have 16 bits, left shift 8 to place the high bits then or to handle the low bits. My question is, **what is the best way to do this in assembly?**

I've ignorantly tried something like this

```
SHIFT_8L macro count
   rlncf    addrH
   movlw    b'11111110'
   andwf    addrH,1
   decfsz count
   bra SHIFT_8L

   movff    addrH, WREG
   iorwf    addrL, 0
   movwf    final
endm
```

But really, all this is doing is just moving `addrL` into `final`. Ultimately I am going to have to multiplexing to see which colour dominates and so what's the most efficient way in doing this?

Thanks!

**Edit 2017/02/21h47** I am using the [PIC18F4620](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39626e.pdf) and am interfacing with a [TCS34725 Colour Sensor](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/TCS34725.pdf).

Comment: 16 bit ADC device? Or else, how does the color sensor information wind up in the PIC18? Why don't you link to the tutorial and link to the specific PIC18 device you are using and link to the color sensor, as well? (Also, moving 16 bits from one place to another in the PIC18 is fairly easy and shouldn't involve a "decfsz" instruction. Don't try to emulate what you incorrectly imagine C is doing.)

Comment: I've updated my answer to give a little more background information. I was following the sample code provided by Adafruit, which can be found here[3]. Now I just started getting data from this sensor, but I am not sure if it is correct the way I am doing so. Accordingly, I've asked another question regarding my setup, which you can browse to see my code here[4].  

[3]: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_TCS34725/blob/master/Adafruit_TCS34725.cpp
  [4]: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/287525/pic18-i2c-with-colour-sensor

Comment: www.piclist.com.

Comment: Many code examples of multi-byte arithmetic.

Comment: These four instructions will move a 16 bit value on a PIC: "MOVF SRC,W", "MOVWF DST", "MOVF SRC+1,W", "MOVWF DST+1". For the PIC18, you could consider: "MOVFF SRC, DST", "MOVFF SRC+1, DST+1" as an alternative. Whether these do a job for you depends, though. And there are memory pages and FSRx indirect pointer registers with different access modes. So it is really up to you in the end how you want to approach it. There is no single answer, though there may be better and worse answers. Study the PIC18 architecture and programming models. You've asked but one of many questions ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a 8 bit machine, you don't need to shift things around by 8 bits.  Just move them into the appropriate byte in the first place.

What you seem to be missing in the code snippet you show is that the accumulator and all data bytes are only 8 bits wide.  Shifting a byte left 8 times will just clear it regardless of the original value.

To do the equivalent of the C code you show:

```
;   In the variable definition section:
;
color1   res     2           ;reserve 2 bytes of RAM for the variable COLOR1

;   Later in executable code:
;
         movff   addrL, color1+0 ;copy addrH:addrL into color1
         movff   addrH, color1+2
```

Using color1 later would be done one byte at a time.  To add it with another 16 bit value, for example: Use ADDWF to add the low bytes, store the result, Use ADDWFC to add the high bytes, store the result.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, what is the best way to do this in assembly?

I would suggest that you step back and ask yourself if you have to do it in assembly. assembly is much more difficult to use and to port than a high level language like C. doing it in C allows you to focus on more value-add things (like logic) rather than those that can be handled by a compiler (math).